# A trip to Patalpani near Indore

Tags: india, safety, event-based-effects

We are bunch of friends from Hyderabad, planning to visit Indore to meet a friend. We are also planning to visit Patalpani, a famous picnic spot. Just wondering after watching these news reports about an accident year ago whether it's safe to visit that place.

Links are : 
[Indian Express newspaper](http://www.indianexpress.com/news/mp-body-of-girl-swept-away-at-patalpani-waterfall-recovered/819623) & [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ptH1AMUVro4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to news reports, that particular [incident happened because of floodwater from heavy rains](http://storyful.com/stories/1000005527). Look out for local weather reports and take precautions in case you find currents are too strong for similar reasons and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

That place is risky, online reporting has started very recently. I've lived close to that place; it is really not advisable from a safety perspective.

It is true that the particular incident was due to flash flooding. http://m.timesofindia.com/city/indore/Police-restrict-entry-into-Choral-river-picnic-spot/articleshow/53258081.cms . Patalpani is a picnic spot near a waterfall, and police restricts entry often. People accidentally drown in the river, or just fall from a height.